# Difference between legions at the end of the Roman empire and around the beginning of the Roman Empire

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, julius-caesar

I'm currently searching for some information about the Roman legions.
Around the time of Julius Caesar and Augustus the legions seem to be more organized and were structured with the same type of troops and numbers.

At the end of the Roman empire I don't find really much information of what kind of troops a legion was shaped of. 
were these legions much different through the influence of foreigners or were they constructed the same as they were in time of Julius Caesar?

Comment: Check out Marian Reforms here for a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marian_reforms

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_army

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link that contains everything you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Roman_army

If you don't trust Wikipedia itself check the sources they cite.

and @Pieter Geerkens, the marian reforms took place during the late roman REPUBLIC (about 100 BCE), stevedc is asking about the roman EMPIRE.

Comment: This was what I'm searching for